# How to implement Matt Calabrese's BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION idea?

Tags: c++, macros

In [a talk from BoostCon 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcsOsV5XSjk), Matt Calabrese gives the following hypothetical syntax:

```
template< class L, class R >
BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION( operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs )
                   , if ( is_vector_udt< L > )
                        ( is_vector_udt< R > )
                   , try ( lhs + rhs )
                         ( -rhs )
                   , if typename ( L::value_type )
                   )
(
  return lhs + -rhs
)
```

The idea is that this declares a function template:

1. named `operator-`,
2. with arguments `L const& lhs` and `R const& rhs`,
3. which does not participate in overload resolution unless `is_vector_udt<L>` and `is_vector_udt<R>` are true,
4. which does not participate in overload resolution unless `lhs + rhs` and `-rhs` are valid expressions,
5. which does not participate in overload resolution unless `L::value_type` is a valid type,
6. whose body is `return lhs + -rhs;`, and
7. with return type deduced from the given body;

using concepts-like syntax without actual language-level concepts (it's supposed to work in the C++11 we got, not the one we wanted).

I'm most interested in points 3, 4, and 5 in the list above. The proposed syntax repurposes words that would normally be keywords. For example, `try` here obviously does not refer to exception handling, but the macro would have to transform `try(lhs+rhs)(-rhs)` into something that could participate in SFINAE, such as `sizeof((void)(lhs+rhs),(void)(-rhs),0)`, but only if it occurs inside an invocation of the `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` macro. I'm not familiar with advanced preprocessing techniques so I can't figure out how this could be done.

Or maybe I misunderstood, and Calabrese wasn't actually claiming that this syntax was implementable (though that would be strange; I would think that he would have instead chosen to show some syntax that is implementable).

Comment: At a glance, I assume the macro is using concatenation to prepend something, e.g., `try` becomes `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION_ARG_try` and that would be predefined as a function macro. The case of `if typename` is pretty interesting, though.

Comment: There's not much info out there about this, but there is a [Boost discussion](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/10/171516.php). While it seems there's no code available for his more final implementation, toward the [end of that thread](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/10/172191.php) is where there's more resemblance. He does say two-word IDs can't use the same first word as a one-word ID. So he found some black magic to get around that or maybe the slide has a mistake. Asking him to remember a decade-old effort might be the best you get for `if typename`.

Comment: For those interested: The slides for the talk are [available here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/master/thu/Boost.Generic.pdf) (The YT Video unfornately is only available in 480p, which makes it hard to read the slides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr:

- As it is `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` would have not been implementable in C++11

  - The SFINAE parts would have worked without a problem
  - The return-type deduction from arbitrary statements would have been impossible, due to lambdas not being allowed in unevaluated contexts
- A slightly modified version of `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` is possible, that doesn't deduce the return type from the expressions but rather another parameter.
  e.g.:

  ```cpp
  template< class L, class R >
  BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION( operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs ),
                     lhs + -rhs // <- this will be used to deduce the return type
                   , if ( is_vector_udt< L > )
                        ( is_vector_udt< R > )
                   , try ( lhs + rhs )
                         ( -rhs )
                   , if typename ( L::value_type )
                   )
  (
    return lhs + -rhs
  )
  ```
- Here's a full implementation of how this modified `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` would look like:

  - [Standard C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/3hWfnM7YM)
  - [with Boost.PP](https://godbolt.org/z/3hfq87Gff)

The rest of this post goes into the details of how to build `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` in C++11 using macros without any libraries:

---

##### 1. Parsing the conditions

Let's first start with a macro that can parse a single condition list from the `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` macro (e.g. `if (A)(B)(C)` / `try (A)(B)` into something we can use in C++.

The basis for this is - as @chris metioned in the comments - [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html). By prepending a fixed token we can convert `if` / `try` into macro names for further processing.

Such a `PARSE_COND` macro could look like this:

```cpp
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)

#define COND_if    <-IF->
#define COND_try   <-TRY->

#define PARSE_COND(expr) CONCAT(COND_,expr)
```

This already allows us to replace the leading `if` / `try` with anything we want.

Macro Expansion Examples: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8vdsKvMW3)

```
PARSE_COND(if (A)(B))              =>      <-IF-> (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(try (A)(B))             =>      <-TRY-> (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(if typename (A)(B))     =>      <-IF-> typename (A)(B)
```

We can use this technique to substitute the `if` / `try` with a call to another sets of macros (`HANDLE_IF` / `HANDLE_TRY`) that will handle the next stage of processing: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W8n3Ej4PK)

```cpp
#define COND_if    HANDLE_IF (
#define COND_try   HANDLE_TRY (

#define HANDLE_IF(expr) DOIF: expr
#define HANDLE_TRY(expr) DOTRY: expr 

#define PARSE_COND(expr) CONCAT(COND_,expr))
```

```
PARSE_COND(if (A)(B))              =>      DOIF: (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(try (A)(B))             =>      DOTRY: (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(if typename (A)(B))     =>      DOIF: typename (A)(B)
```

##### 1.1 Handling multi-token identifiers like `if typename`

Now we need to deal with distinguishing a plain `if` from `if typename`.
Unfortunately we can't utilize the same approach as for `if` / `try`, because  concatenation needs to result in a valid preprocessor token - and concatenating something to an opening parenthesis will always produce an invalid token => we'd get a preprocessor error.

e.g. something like this would work fine for `if typename`, but would cause an error with just `if`: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5zEaWMPhx)

```cpp
#define COND_IF_typename HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME ( 
#define COND_IF_(...) HANDLE_IF_IF ( (__VA_ARGS__)

#define HANDLE_IF(expr) CONCAT(COND_IF_, expr))

#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME(expr) DOIFTYPENAME: expr
#define HANDLE_IF_IF(expr) DOIF: expr
```

```
PARSE_COND(if typename (A)(B))     =>      DOIFTYPENAME: (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(if (A)(B))              =>      <compiler error>
```

So we need a way to detect if there are more tokens left to be parsed (e.g. `typename`) or if we've already reached the parenthesized conditions.

For this we'll have to use some macro-shenanigans - it is actually possible to check if an expression starts with something parenthesized or not by using function-like macros.

If the name of a function-like macro is followed by parenthesis it will expand, otherwise the name of the macro will be left untouched.

Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fov95e6b5)

```cpp
#define CHECK(...) EXPANDED!
#define EXPANSION_CHECK(expr) CHECK expr
```

```
EXPANSION_CHECK((A)(B))              =>      EXPANDED!(B)
EXPANSION_CHECK(typename (A)(B))     =>      CHECK typename (A)(B)
```

By using this property of function-like macros we can write a macro that can detect if there are more tokens in a given expression: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T7bYfqq8a)

```cpp
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(id) id EMPTY()

#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS(expr) EXPAND(DEFER(HAS_MORE_TOKENS_RESULT)(HAS_MORE_TOKENS_CHECK expr, 0, 1))
#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS_CHECK(...) ~,~
#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS_RESULT(a, b, c, ...) c
```

```
HAS_MORE_TOKENS(typename (A)(B))     =>      1
HAS_MORE_TOKENS((A)(B))              =>      0
```

Using this we can now handle any sequence of tokens - if there are more tokens we can use the `CONCAT()`-trick to further expand them, and if we've reached the parenthesized conditions we can stop and know which sequence of tokens we've read before.

Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YrbYY6x68)

```cpp
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)

#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(id) id EMPTY()

#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS(expr) EXPAND(DEFER(HAS_MORE_TOKENS_RESULT)(HAS_MORE_TOKENS_CHECK expr, 0, 1))
#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS_CHECK(...) ~,~
#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS_RESULT(a, b, c, ...) c

#define IIF(condition, a, b) CONCAT(IIF_, condition)(a, b)
#define IIF_0(a, b) b
#define IIF_1(a, b) a

#define COND_if    HANDLE_IF (
#define COND_try   HANDLE_TRY (

#define COND_IF_typename HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME (

#define HANDLE_IF(expr) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(expr), HANDLE_IF_MORE, HANDLE_IF_IF)(expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_MORE(expr) CONCAT(COND_IF_,expr))

#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME(expr) DOIFTYPENAME: expr
#define HANDLE_IF_IF(expr) DOIF: expr
#define HANDLE_TRY(expr) DOTRY: expr 

#define PARSE_COND(expr) CONCAT(COND_,expr))
```

```
PARSE_COND(if (A)(B))              =>      DOIF: (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(try (A)(B))             =>      DOTRY: (A)(B)
PARSE_COND(if typename (A)(B))     =>      DOIFTYPENAME: (A)(B)
```

###### 1.2 Building SFINAE expressions

Next we need to convert the actual expressions into valid C++ SFINAE code for the 3 different types of checks.

We'll inject the checks into the return-type, e.g.:

```cpp
template<class L, class R>
auto operator+(L const&, R const&) -> decltype(<check A>, <check B>, <actual deduced return type>) {
  /* ... */
}
```

- For `if` we can use `std::enable_if`:
  `expr` -> `typename std::enable_if<expr::value>::type()`
  This will result in `void()` if `expr` is true, and produce a substitution error if `expr` is false
- For `try` we can just leave the expression as it is.
- For `if typename` we can use `std::declval`:
  `expr` -> `std::declval<typename expr>()`
  We need to use `std::declval` because `expr` might not be default-constructible.

So with a small foreach macro we can now convert all 3 types of SFINAE-conditions into C++-Code: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ExY4ha7j5)

```cpp
#define SEQ_HEAD(seq) EXPAND(DEFER(SEQ_HEAD_IMPL)(SEQ_HEAD_EL seq))
#define SEQ_HEAD_EL(el) el,
#define SEQ_HEAD_IMPL(head, tail) head
#define SEQ_TAIL(seq) SEQ_TAIL_IMPL seq
#define SEQ_TAIL_IMPL(el)

#define FOR_EACH(func, seq) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(seq), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_0)(func, seq)
#define FOR_EACH_END(...)
#define FOR_EACH_0(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_1)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_1(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_2)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_2(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_3)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_3(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_4)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_4(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_END)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))

#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME(expr) FOR_EACH(HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME_IMPL, expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME_IMPL(expr) std::declval<typename expr>(),
#define HANDLE_IF_IF(expr) FOR_EACH(HANDLE_IF_IF_IMPL, expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_IF_IMPL(expr) typename std::enable_if<expr::value>::type(),
#define HANDLE_TRY(expr) FOR_EACH(HANDLE_TRY_IMPL, expr)
#define HANDLE_TRY_IMPL(expr) expr,
```

```
PARSE_COND(if (A)(B))              =>      typename std::enable_if<A::value>::type(), typename std::enable_if<B::value>::type(),
PARSE_COND(try (A)(B))             =>      A, B,
PARSE_COND(if typename (A)(B))     =>      std::declval<typename A>(), std::declval<typename B>(),
```

---

##### 2. Building `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION`

Now that we can parse the conditions, we almost have everything we need to get an actual implementation of `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION`.

We just need another `FOR_EACH` implementation to loop over the different condition lists passed to `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION`, and a few more macros:

```cpp
#define FOR_EACH_I(func, seq) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(seq), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_0)(func, seq)
#define FOR_EACH_I_END(...)
#define FOR_EACH_I_0(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_1)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_1(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_2)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_2(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_3)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_3(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_4)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_4(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_END)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))


#define TUP_SIZE(...) TUP_SIZE_IMPL(,##__VA_ARGS__,3,2,1,0)
#define TUP_SIZE_IMPL(a,b,c,d,e,...) e
#define TUP_TO_SEQ(...) CONCAT(TUP_TO_SEQ_, TUP_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_0()
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_1(a) (a)
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_2(a,b) (a)(b)
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_3(a,b,c) (a)(b)(c)

#define HANDLE_CONDS(...) FOR_EACH_I(PARSE_COND, TUP_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define INFER_RETURN_TYPE(...) ([&]() { __VA_ARGS__; })()
#define BUILD_FUNC_BODY(...) INFER_RETURN_TYPE(__VA_ARGS__)) { __VA_ARGS__; }
#define BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION(signature, ...) auto signature -> decltype( HANDLE_CONDS(__VA_ARGS__) BUILD_FUNC_BODY
```

And that's already it - now we have implemented `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION`: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j43dr3348)

```cpp
template< class L, class R >
BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION( operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs )
                   , if ( is_vector_udt< L > )
                        ( is_vector_udt< R > )
                   , try ( lhs + rhs )
                         ( -rhs )
                   , if typename ( L::value_type )
                   )
(
  return lhs + -rhs
)
```

```cpp
template< class L, class R >
auto operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs ) -> decltype(
    typename std::enable_if<is_vector_udt< L >::value>::type(),
    typename std::enable_if<is_vector_udt< R >::value>::type(),
    lhs + rhs,
    -rhs,
    std::declval<typename L::value_type>(),
    ([&]() { return lhs + -rhs; })()) // <- problem
{
    return lhs + -rhs;
}
```

There's a problem though - lambdas can't be used in unevaluated contexts (in C++20 they now can be used, but only without capture-clauses).
So this unfortunately doesn't compile as it is.

There's also no easy workaround for this (at least in C++11 - in C++14 we could use automatic return type deduction) - so unfortunately as it is `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` would not have been implementable as-is in C++11.

---

##### 3. Making it work

One way you could make `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` viable in C++11 could be by removing the last feature from your list:

> 7. with return type deduced from the given body;

If we e.g. add an additional parameter to `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` specifically for return-type deduction it would work:

```cpp
template< class L, class R >
BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION( operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs ),
                     lhs + -rhs // <- this will be used for return-type deduction
                   , if ( is_vector_udt< L > )
                        ( is_vector_udt< R > )
                   , try ( lhs + rhs )
                         ( -rhs )
                   , if typename ( L::value_type )
                   )
(
  return lhs + -rhs
)
```

Then we just need to slightly modify our existing macros to make it work: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3hWfnM7YM)

```cpp
#define HANDLE_CONDS(...) FOR_EACH_I(PARSE_COND, TUP_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define BUILD_FUNC_BODY(...) { __VA_ARGS__; }
#define BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION(signature, return_type, ...) auto signature -> decltype( HANDLE_CONDS(__VA_ARGS__) return_type) BUILD_FUNC_BODY
```

And now we actually have a working `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION` implementation!

Here's the code the above example would produce: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rhWPePYd1)

```cpp
template< class L, class R >
auto operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs ) -> decltype(
    typename std::enable_if<is_vector_udt< L >::value>::type(),
    typename std::enable_if<is_vector_udt< R >::value>::type(),
    lhs + rhs,
    -rhs,
    std::declval<typename L::value_type>(),
    lhs + -rhs // <- expression from our additional parameter
) {
    return lhs + -rhs;
}
```

##### 3. Full Code & [`Boost.PP`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) Implementation

This is the full implementation of our slightly modified `BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION`: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3hWfnM7YM)

```cpp
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)

#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(id) id EMPTY()

#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS(expr) EXPAND(DEFER(HAS_MORE_TOKENS_RESULT)(HAS_MORE_TOKENS_CHECK expr, 0, 1))
#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS_CHECK(...) ~,~
#define HAS_MORE_TOKENS_RESULT(a, b, c, ...) c

#define IIF(condition, a, b) CONCAT(IIF_, condition)(a, b)
#define IIF_0(a, b) b
#define IIF_1(a, b) a

#define SEQ_HEAD(seq) EXPAND(DEFER(SEQ_HEAD_IMPL)(SEQ_HEAD_EL seq))
#define SEQ_HEAD_EL(el) el,
#define SEQ_HEAD_IMPL(head, tail) head
#define SEQ_TAIL(seq) SEQ_TAIL_IMPL seq
#define SEQ_TAIL_IMPL(el)

#define FOR_EACH(func, seq) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(seq), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_0)(func, seq)
#define FOR_EACH_END(...)
#define FOR_EACH_0(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_1)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_1(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_2)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_2(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_3)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_3(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_4)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_4(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_END, FOR_EACH_END)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))

#define FOR_EACH_I(func, seq) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(seq), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_0)(func, seq)
#define FOR_EACH_I_END(...)
#define FOR_EACH_I_0(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_1)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_1(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_2)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_2(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_3)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_3(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_4)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOR_EACH_I_4(func, seq) func(SEQ_HEAD(seq)) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(SEQ_TAIL(seq)), FOR_EACH_I_END, FOR_EACH_I_END)(func, SEQ_TAIL(seq))


#define TUP_SIZE(...) TUP_SIZE_IMPL(,##__VA_ARGS__,3,2,1,0)
#define TUP_SIZE_IMPL(a,b,c,d,e,...) e
#define TUP_TO_SEQ(...) CONCAT(TUP_TO_SEQ_, TUP_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_0()
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_1(a) (a)
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_2(a,b) (a)(b)
#define TUP_TO_SEQ_3(a,b,c) (a)(b)(c)


#define COND_if    HANDLE_IF (
#define COND_try   HANDLE_TRY (

#define COND_IF_typename HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME (

#define HANDLE_IF(expr) IIF(HAS_MORE_TOKENS(expr), HANDLE_IF_MORE, HANDLE_IF_IF)(expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_MORE(expr) CONCAT(COND_IF_,expr))

#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME(expr) FOR_EACH(HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME_IMPL, expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME_IMPL(expr) std::declval<typename expr>(),
#define HANDLE_IF_IF(expr) FOR_EACH(HANDLE_IF_IF_IMPL, expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_IF_IMPL(expr) typename std::enable_if<expr::value>::type(),
#define HANDLE_TRY(expr) FOR_EACH(HANDLE_TRY_IMPL, expr)
#define HANDLE_TRY_IMPL(expr) expr,

#define PARSE_COND(expr) CONCAT(COND_,expr))

#define HANDLE_CONDS(...) FOR_EACH_I(PARSE_COND, TUP_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define BUILD_FUNC_BODY(...) { __VA_ARGS__; }
#define BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION(signature, return_type, ...) auto signature -> decltype( HANDLE_CONDS(__VA_ARGS__) return_type) BUILD_FUNC_BODY



// Usage:
template< class L, class R >
BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION( operator -( L const& lhs, R const& rhs ),
                     lhs + -rhs
                   , if ( is_vector_udt< L > )
                        ( is_vector_udt< R > )
                   , try ( lhs + rhs )
                         ( -rhs )
                   , if typename ( L::value_type )
                   )
(
  return lhs + -rhs
)
```

With Boost Preprocessor we could cut down on a lot of the boilerplate macro code.

This is how the same implementation would look with with boost pp: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3hfq87Gff)

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define COND_if    HANDLE_IF (
#define COND_try   HANDLE_TRY (

#define COND_IF_typename HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME (

#define HANDLE_IF(expr) BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_IS_BEGIN_PARENS(expr), HANDLE_IF_IF, HANDLE_IF_MORE)(expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_MORE(expr) BOOST_PP_CAT(COND_IF_,expr))

#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME(expr) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME_IMPL, ~, expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_TYPENAME_IMPL(r, _, expr) std::declval<typename expr>(),
#define HANDLE_IF_IF(expr) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(HANDLE_IF_IF_IMPL, ~, expr)
#define HANDLE_IF_IF_IMPL(r, _, expr) typename std::enable_if<expr::value>::type(),
#define HANDLE_TRY(expr) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(HANDLE_TRY_IMPL, ~, expr)
#define HANDLE_TRY_IMPL(r, _, expr) expr,

#define PARSE_COND(r, _, i, expr) BOOST_PP_CAT(COND_,expr))

#define TUP_TO_SEQ(...) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__))
#define HANDLE_CONDS(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I( PARSE_COND, ~, TUP_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define BUILD_FUNC_BODY(...) { __VA_ARGS__; }
#define BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION(signature, return_type, ...) auto signature -> decltype( HANDLE_CONDS(__VA_ARGS__) return_type) BUILD_FUNC_BODY
```

---

##### 4. Additional resources

- [Slides from the Boost.Generic talk by Matt Calabrese](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/master/thu/Boost.Generic.pdf)
- [C Preprocessor tricks, tips, and idioms](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#deferred-expression) - a nice overview of commonly used preprocessor tricks by Paul Fultz

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wish to have a function participate in the overload list depending on certain conditions. There are several constructs you can use to achieve your goals. We are going to use `std::enable_if_t` which leverages `SFINAE` properties of C++.

You can find the documentation for `std::enable_if_t` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

The following solution targets C++11 and above.

First we will create a vector type that has the operators you want and a trait to check that a type matches the type of our vector. Below is a small code example to declare and test this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template<typename V>
struct My_vector
{
    My_vector(std::vector<V> const &init) : v_(init) {}
    My_vector(std::initializer_list<V> const &init) : v_(init) {}

    My_vector operator-()
    {
        std::vector<V> res(v_);
        for (auto & a : res)
            a = -a;
        return res;
    }
    template<typename U>
    My_vector operator+(My_vector<U> const & rhs)
    {
        assert (rhs.v_.size() ==  v_.size());
        std::vector<V> res(v_);
        for(auto l = res.begin(), r = rhs.v_.begin(); l != res.end(); l++, r++)
            *l = *l + *r;
        return res;
    }
    
    std::vector<V> v_;
};
template<typename T>
struct is_my_vector : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_my_vector<My_vector<T>> : std::true_type {};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    My_vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 3};
    My_vector<double> v2 {4, 5, 6};
    
    auto v3 = v1 + v2;
    auto v4 = -v2;
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_my_vector<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_my_vector<decltype(v1)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_my_vector<decltype(v2)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_my_vector<decltype(v3)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_my_vector<decltype(v4)>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Now we can make declare our `-` operator like this:

```
template<
    typename L, 
    typename R, 
    typename = std::enable_if_t<is_my_vector<L>::value, L*>,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<is_my_vector<R>::value, R*>
>
auto operator-(L const & lhs, R const & rhs) -> decltype(lhs + -rhs)
{
    return lhs + -rhs;
}
```

Declaring it this way with `std::enable_if_t` will insure that the function will be considered only if `L` & `R` are of some `My_vector<T>`.

Note that the expression in `decltype` is evaluated at compilation and there is no runtime overhead. I think that from C++14 onwards you can omit the return decltype altogether.

To test this just create a type that has the `operator-` and `operator+` like we did for My_vector and try to substruct one instance from the other =  The compilation will fail. If you however remove the `typename = std::enable_if_t` lines from the template definition you will se your code compiles OK.

This may not be 100% what you want because we are not checking for the existence of the `-` & `+` operators in a `SFINAE` way but since we know our types have these operators it is not necessary